# List of pairs, find those who are not

Tags: python, ruby, regex

I read a list of pairs in the filesystem (Linux)...
UniqueDocument.xml
UniqueDocument.pdf

I need to find the entries that does not have a xml file, then I need to fetch it.

Been trying with os.list and regex but havent found a sutible solution and Dir() in Ruby. But I cant get to the end... my mind blocks me.

Comment: Provide the code you have tried and how it fails. Provide at least some sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby,

```
# Get an array of file names for pdf and xml
pdf=Dir.glob("test/*.pdf").map {|f| File.basename(f, '.pdf')}
xml=Dir.glob("test/*.xml").map {|f| File.basename(f, '.xml')}

# Make the difference between xml and pdf to get file names that have a pdf file but no xml
p pdf - xml
```

How does it work ?

1. `Dir.glob("test/*.pdf")`

returns an array with the path to all pdf files in folder `test`. Looks like `["test/foo.pdf", ...]`.

2. `File.basename('test/foo.pdf', '.pdf')`

returns the file name without the extension. In this case, will return `'foo'` .

3. `Dir.glob("test/*.pdf").map {|f| File.basename(f, '.pdf')}`

returns an array of file names without extension, taking only pdf files.

4. `pdf - xml`

returns all strings that are in pdf but not in xml.